# Firefox profiles with Selenium and Marionette

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I didn't find an answer to this. To automate some tests I have used Firefox and Selenium. I thought to give a try to Selenium 3.0 and its Marionette interface.  Everything works with an old Firefox binary and the old webdriver way, so my code as such works.

For my tests I have created a Firefox profile, which I then pass to Selenium. Previously I did it like this:

```
p = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("profilename")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=p, firefox_binary="/path/to/ff")
```

This works. My browser starts and whatever modifications it makes to the profile (cookies), seem to be there when I restart the browser with the same profile.

With Marionette/geckodriver the instructions tell me to use capabilities["profile"] for this, and they state this should be *"Base64-encoded zip of a profile directory to use as the profile for the Firefox instance"*.

Ok. First, how do I create a base64-encoded zip in Python? Or do I just use shell for this?

Second, how does this work in practice? If I zip and base64 encode my profile directory, how do I then get the modified version back after my tests complete? If I created this file in shell and kept passing the same file for consecutive attempts, every modification, for example a login cookie, would be lost, and I would need to start from the scratch again, which in this case is not desirable.

I can keep using the old system at least for now, this is just to satisfy my curiosity.

Hannu